# The cast to value type System.Boolean failed because the materialized value is null, result type's generic parameter must use a nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This code was working before but now I've got this error: **The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> BankDepositVoucher(BankDepositVoucherSearchViewModel search, int? PageNo)
        {
            var model = new BankDepositVoucherListViewModel
            {
                Search = search ?? new BankDepositVoucherSearchViewModel()
            };
            if (search != null)
            {
                search.StartDate = search.StartDate.ToStartOfDay();
                search.EndDate = search.EndDate.ToEndOfDay();
            }
            try
            {
                var Vouchers = DbManager.Invoices.Include(x => x.BankDepositVoucher)
                                             .Where(x => x.Type == InvoiceType.BankDepositVoucher
                                             && (x.VoucherNumber == search.VoucherNo || search.VoucherNo == null)
                                             && (x.BankDepositVoucher.SlipNo.Contains(search.SlipNo) || search.SlipNo == null)
                                             && (x.BankDepositVoucher.ChequeNo.Contains(search.ChequeNo) || search.ChequeNo == null)
                                             && (x.BankDepositVoucher.Bank.AccountName.Contains(search.BankDetails)
                                             || search.BankDetails == null)
                                             && (x.BankDepositVoucher.AccountName.Contains(search.AccountName) || search.AccountName == null)
                                             && (x.BankDepositVoucher.Narration.Contains(search.Narration) || search.Narration == null)
                                             && (x.TotalAmount == search.Amount || search.Amount == null)
                                             && (x.Date >= search.StartDate || search.StartDate == null)
                                              && (x.Date <= search.EndDate || search.EndDate == null));
                //model.Pager = new Pager(await Vouchers.CountAsync(), PageNo, 10);
                model.Vouchers = await Vouchers.OrderByDescending(x => x.VoucherNumber)
                                    //.Skip((model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * model.Pager.PageSize)
                                    //.Take(model.Pager.PageSize)
                                    .Select(x => new BankDepositVoucherBaseViewModel
                                    {
                                        Id = x.Id,
                                        VoucherNumber = x.VoucherNumber,
                                        AccountName = x.BankDepositVoucher.AccountName,
                                        BankAccountName = x.BankDepositVoucher.Bank.AccountName,
                                        Date = x.Date,
                                        ChequeNo = x.BankDepositVoucher.ChequeNo,
                                        Narration = x.BankDepositVoucher.Narration,
                                        SlipNo = x.BankDepositVoucher.SlipNo,
                                        TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                                        IsCleared = x.BankDepositVoucher.IsCleared
                                    }).ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("", ex.Message);

            }
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

This is the part throwing above mentioned exception

```
model.Vouchers = await Vouchers.OrderByDescending(x => x.VoucherNumber)
                                    //.Skip((model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * model.Pager.PageSize)
                                    //.Take(model.Pager.PageSize)
                                    .Select(x => new BankDepositVoucherBaseViewModel
                                    {
                                        Id = x.Id,
                                        VoucherNumber = x.VoucherNumber,
                                        AccountName = x.BankDepositVoucher.AccountName,
                                        BankAccountName = x.BankDepositVoucher.Bank.AccountName,
                                        Date = x.Date,
                                        ChequeNo = x.BankDepositVoucher.ChequeNo,
                                        Narration = x.BankDepositVoucher.Narration,
                                        SlipNo = x.BankDepositVoucher.SlipNo,
                                        TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                                        IsCleared = x.BankDepositVoucher.IsCleared
                                    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: There is a `bool` property in `Vouchers` which is nullable on DB side. Find it and make it `bool?` or non-nullable on DB side.

Comment: My guess to find the problem data: SELECT * FROM bankdepositvoucher WHERE iscleared is null

Comment: @ZorgoZ The `IsCleared` property is a `bool`, but it is non-nullable on both sides i.e in the ViewModel and DB as well.

Comment: @CaiusJard Tried that when the exception occured, no such records exist.

Comment: Try turning on "break upon thrown" for all managed exceptions and see if you can trap the call stack deep enough to find out which property is being assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that when populating the view model it cannot deal with the fact that a record may not have a BankDepositVoucher.

For instance: 
`IsCleared = x.BankDepositVoucher.IsCleared`

This should probably be: 
`IsCleared = x.BankDepositVoucher?.IsCleared ?? false`

One other thing to improve performance considerably:

While it may look concise in the code to write statements like this:

```
.Where(x => x.Type == InvoiceType.BankDepositVoucher
    && (x.VoucherNumber == search.VoucherNo || search.VoucherNo == null)
    && (x.BankDepositVoucher.SlipNo.Contains(search.SlipNo) || search.SlipNo == null)
    && (x.BankDepositVoucher.ChequeNo.Contains(search.ChequeNo) || search.ChequeNo == null)
    && (x.BankDepositVoucher.Bank.AccountName.Contains(search.BankDetails)
        || search.BankDetails == null)
    && (x.BankDepositVoucher.AccountName.Contains(search.AccountName) || search.AccountName == null)
    && (x.BankDepositVoucher.Narration.Contains(search.Narration) || search.Narration == null)
    && (x.TotalAmount == search.Amount || search.Amount == null)
    && (x.Date >= search.StartDate || search.StartDate == null)
    && (x.Date <= search.EndDate || search.EndDate == null));
```

It is more efficient to write it out as:

```
.Where(x => x.Type == InvoiceType.BankDepositVoucher);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.VoucherNo))
    Voucher = Voucher.Where(x => x.VoucherNumber == search.VoucherNo);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SlipNo))
    Voucher = Voucher.Where(x => x.BankDepositVoucher.SlipNo.Contains(search.SlipNo))
// etc.
```

The reason is that in the first case you are generating a much larger SQL statement to be sent to the database, and it is quite easy to "slip up" on conditions if that query is ever edited in the future. (missing parenthesis, etc.) The second example only adds conditions to the query if they are needed, keeping the resulting SQL statement much more compact.